# Unpublish node created upon checkout

Tags: rules, nodes, commerce

Looking to tie a recurring product to the published status of the node it created.  I've tried this by creating a node on checkout in a number of ways, but my most recent and promising attempt involves line items and rules creating the node on checkout and setting data values for it coming from the line items, similar to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiGiLApejrY) by Josh Miller.

My thought is to use a recurring product type and have the node publish on completed payment of that product.  Then, at some point in the future, when the user/customer cancels the subscription to the recurring product, the node that was created upon initial payment should be unpublished.  Additionally, the node would be deleted (also by rules) after a given unpublished grace period.

Note: I have used the [Commerce Node Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout) module, but am not able to select multiple products at a time.  I'm also aware of the Commerce License Node module, but considering the lack of documentation I've found, do not have a lot of confidence in the progress I've made there thus far.

So, any thoughts/ideas on how to use rules to unpublish the node created at checkout when the recurring product expires upon user cancellation?

Clarification:  I'm able to create a node through line items, save it, and publish it on successful payment at checkout.  The problem is connecting the created node to the recurring product/order that created it beyond the moment of creation.  In other words, I'm stuck at trying to use rules to unpublish the node in the future according to the status of the order that originally created it.

I could set an interval field on the node upon creation equal to the value of the interval of the recurring product/order, but that does not allow the node to react to changes in the order going forward.  So, if the node has a value (let's say 12 months), and the recurring product/order has a corresponding value (also 12 months), I could use rules to tell the node to unpublish after that period on the node (12 months).  But what if the order is renewed or set to be unlimited until cancellation?  The order and payment will continue beyond the original period (12+ months), but the node will unpublish according to its original static value (12 months).

I have tried using rules to look at the Order ID and work back from there to the entity created (node), but I think I need to make a more concrete connection between the node and the order first.  I've considered using a node reference field on the product, but haven't figured out how to connect that field to the entity created either.  Maybe I'm off in how I'm approaching this, but it feels like the answers just around the corner.  So, how do I use rules to unpublish a node according to the status of the recurring order that created it through rules?

Comment: Rules has an unpublish Action... so where are you stuck?